# Changing Background of animating UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` using `UIView animateWithDuration` to translate it down the screen. When the `UIButton` is pressed it get hidden. But `[self.squareOne setHidden:NO];` is at the beginning of the method to make it reappear. The completion block:

```
completion:^(BOOL complete) {
                         if (complete) {
                             if (self.squareOne.hidden==YES) {
                                 [self squareOneMover]; //squareOneMover is the method the animation is created
                             }
                         }
                     }
```

This makes the animation repeat as long as the `UIButton` has been pressed, but for some reason when I add this right before `[self squareOneMover]`:

```
[self squareOneColour];
```

The completion doesn't take place, hence the loop stops. `squareOneColour`:

```
- (void) squareOneColour {
    NSUInteger r = arc4random_uniform(5);
    [self.squareOne setBackgroundImage:[self.colorImageArray objectAtIndex:r] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

What I want is to have `squareOne` background change so that on the next animation it looks different. How do I do that?

Comment: Can you show where you added the code? Place [self squareOneColour]; before [self squareOneMover]